# How can I use ES6 modules to import momentjs and make babel-loader transpile it to es5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, momentjs, babel-loader

In my `webpack.conf.js` I set babel-loader like this

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'),resolve('node_modules/moment')],
    options: {
      presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }]],
      plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']
    }
  },
```

And I would like to just `import moment from 'moment'`, but webpack issues the warning,

> export 'default' (imported as 'moment') was not found in 'moment'

I tried the suggestion here, [How can I import momentjs in es6?](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608#issuecomment-336059877)
e.g. using `import moment from 'moment/src/moment'` then I got another warning

> This relative module was not found:
>
> - ./locale in ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js

I have used `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin 1.1` to minify my codes and IE11 can access them, which makes me believe there should be a simple way to make babel-loader transpile my code to es5 and let IE access them.

Comment: momentjs is already ES5 (syntax at least) - it also seems to polyfill as required too - what makes you think it isn't

Comment: I was talking about import moment from 'moment' and let IE access my codes.

Comment: oh, your title suggests you want to transpile momentjs - my mistake

Comment: Change the title, thanks